# Инициализация атрибутов класса на основе пользовательского ввода

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Как инициализировать вводные данные от пользователя в классе? выдает ошибку **init**() missing 1 required positional argument:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
 
@dataclass
class Figure(object):
    edge: float
 
    def area(self): return NotImplemented
 
    def bulk(self): return NotImplemented
 
@dataclass
class Cube(Figure):
 
    def area(self):
        return self.edge**2 * 6
 
    def bulk(self):
        return self.edge**3
 
@dataclass
class Cylinder(Figure):
    radius: float
 
    def area(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius * (self.edge + self.radius)
 
    def bulk(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius**2 * self.edge
 
@dataclass
class Tetrahedron(Figure):
 
    def area(self):
        return 3**(1/2) * self.edge**2
 
    def bulk(self):
        return 3**(1/2) / 12 * self.edge**3

def main():
    print('1: Куб')
    print('2: Цилиндр')
    print('3: Тетраэдр')
    fig = input('Выберите фигуру: ')
    if fig == '1':
        print('1: площадь')
        print('2: объем')
        sposob = input('Выберите способ: ')
        if sposob == '1':
            u1 = Cube()
            print(u1.area(edge=float(input('Введите длину стороны: '))))
        elif sposob == '2':
            u2 = Cube()
            print(u2.bulk(edge=float(input('Введите длину стороны: '))))
```

Comment: спасибо за внимание, внизу уже помогли, прошу прощения за потраченное время и благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```py
        if sposob == '1':
            u1 = Cube(edge=float(input('Введите данные: ')))
            print(u1.area())
```

Ругается он на то что при создании класса пропущен обязательный аргумент.
В остальном коде правки аналогичные.

Comment: спасибо, ваш ответ помог, заработало.